# Vuejs conditional rendering v-if

Tags: vue.js

I have this part of code wherein in my view theres a condition if I want to show it or not

`<div v-if="toShow" ref="target"></div>`

and in my javascript code I trigger toShow to true

`this.toShow = true`

`this.$refs.target // always null`

but when I use `setTimeout()` the value is not null

I need a solution wherein I dont want to use `setTimeout()` because I'm toggling `toShow` everytime for my transition so what happens is a have a lot of nested `setTimeout()` in my code.

Comment: Can you explain what you're going to use `this.$refs.target` for? There might be a way around it so that you don't need to use it. The only other alternative would be to use `v-show` which includes the element but hides it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [$nextTick](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick) which waits until the next DOM update cycle. It should be much better than setTimeout because it gets called quickly after the DOM updates rather than a specific time later.

I've created a fiddle below showing it working.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: () => {
    return {
      show: false
    };
  },
  methods: {

    toggleShow() {
      this.show = !this.show;
      console.log(this.$refs.target);

      this.$nextTick(() => {
        console.log(this.$refs.target);
      });
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="toggleShow">Toggle Show</button>

  <div v-if="show">
    <h5>Showing</h5>
    <div ref="target"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: nice solution but same concept with setTimeout